# Why is dark matter called dark matter?

Tags: cosmology, terminology, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

It has been observered that spiral arm formation galaxies exist. This is a problem because due to the laws of gravitation, stars close the galactic center should orbit with a much higher angular velocity than stars at the distant edge of a galaxy, and so any structure, spiral arms included, should smear out after one or more revolutions of the stars and become a disk galaxy.

In order to explain this unexpected observation, cosmologists hypothesise that something is causing the stars to all orbit at constant angular velocity, so as to keep the structure, spiral arms, intact. The name given to the "something" that causes this is Dark Matter.

There are a number of problems with this hypothesis. Specifically, when two galaxies are near each other, the "matter" that is maintaining constant angular velocity in one galaxy should also be having an effect on the neighbouring galaxy, yet we see no such effect.

Similarly, if the "dark matter" is really a field effect, then the field that causes constant angular velocity for stars in one galaxy should also be having an effect on the neighbouring galaxy, yet again, we see no such effect.

So, given this, is it sensible to consider the term "dark matter" to actually mean matter, or even a field effect. Or is it sensible to consider "dark matter" to be some as yet unidentified effect?

Comment: Dark matter is not a field effect. I don't know what you are even trying to say. Dark matter is matter we can't see with our current technology. There is many forms of dark matter with their own fields of research. Dark matter differs for modified newtonian dynamics specifically because it states that there is matter there, we just can't see it as opposed to there being difference physical affect at play at the scale of galaxies.

Comment: What i am trying to say it that the reason for the existance for the term "dark matter" is purely due to the apparent constant angular velocity of stars orbiting a galactic center. In other words, "dark matter" is the label given to whatever is causing the constant angular velocity. My question is, if dark matter is actual matter, then why dont we see it affecting neighbouring galaxies, when they are in close proximity. Similarly, if dark matter (its just a label after all) is a some kind of field effect, then also why does it not affect neighbouring galaxies ?

Comment: Far as I know dark matter is just matter that we can’t see. It does add to the mass of the galaxy and it does affect other galaxies as they are drawn towards each other.

Comment: Maybe your question should be more like: Why is dark matter considered to be matter? instead of Why is dark matter called dark matter? Because the answer to this question in this form is: Because it does not interact electromagnetically.

Comment: Yes, if dark matter is in fact matter, then is should add to the attraction of galaxies to each other. But much more than that, if two galaxies are in close proximity and are also perpendicular to each other, as in their plane of rotations, then there should be a marked effect of one galaxy on the other. But we just dont see this. Remember, dark matter is usually considered to comprise the vast bulk of the gravitational mass of a galaxy, so the effect of that mass should be quite obvious.

Comment: The dark matter hypothesis fits galactic clusters too, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Galaxy_clusters also rotational curves of galaxies https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_rotation_curve

Comment: More clearly, we can see the effect of the visible matter of one galaxy on another. But, we should see the effect of each galaxies dark matter long before we see the effect of the visible matter. For surely the dark matter is the vast bulk of the gravitational matter, if indeed dark matter is matter.

Comment: Well they do see it https://phys.org/news/2017-08-galaxy-clusters-clues-dark-energy.html   https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=4829

Comment: That article states that astophysicists "suspect" that dark matter exists to explain why galaxies behave the way we see them behave (read, observed constant angular velocity). I understand that dark "matter" sounds like a good hypothesis to begin with. But I am asking, what would really happen if dark matter actually existed. Specifically, should we not see its effects between neighbouring galaxies ?

Comment: By effects between neighbouring galaxies, i dont just mean attraction, i mean perturbations in stellar orbits due to the vast bulk of dark matter.

Comment: I feel it important that there is a common misconception among lay people that the phrase "dark matter" refers to actual matter. It doesn't. It simply refers to whatever is causing constant angular velocity of stars in observered galaxies (specifically spiral arm galaxies). It is not necessarily matter.

Comment: @Tim you seem to have a misconception of what matter is.

Comment: I have sometimes wondered whether "clear matter" would be a better name than "dark matter". Not only does it not emit or reflect light, it does not absorb it either.  If was dark in the usual sense then it would obscure objects behind it.  The "matter" part of the name bothers me less; it just means that if we figure out what is then we may need to expand our concept of matter.

Comment: In the early history of the subject the term of art was "missing mass", which should suggest some of the uncertainty pertaining to the exact cause of the observed effects.

Comment: Tim, do you think quantitatively at all? You say, two effects should exist, "we see no such effect". Have you tried to estimate what the magnitude of these effects should be, according to dark matter theory?

Comment: Echoing Mitchell Porter's comment, consider to back up the claims in the 3rd paragraph (v2) with references.

Answer (score 4):

What made you believe that dark matter doesn't have any effect on neighboring galaxy?

Secondly, dark matter and dark energy are just placeholder names that we don't know anything about. We know whatever it is, its some sort of matter/energy because that's the closest thing we could compare it to.

Also, consider this: We can only observe less 5% of our universe. And you are claiming that this thing what constitutes more than a quarter of our universe has no effect on the rest of it?

Why do we call it dark matter? Matter? because it interacts with our "visible matter" through gravity. We calculated gravity of all the visible matter and realized that 85% of gravity is still missing. We figured that since gravity comes from matter as it bends the fabric of space-time. Maybe there is another matter that bends the fabric as well but we can't observe it (hence dark).

There are plenty of effects of dark matter that we observe and "galaxy's spiral-arm" thing is one of the many effects of dark matter.

Comment: That is exactly the point I am making, that dark matter is just a "label" to for whatever causes constant angular velocity in stars around a galactic center. And, as you mentioned, that dark energy is just a "label" for whatever is causing in increase in accelaration of galaxies away from each other. I agree entirely. They are just placeholders. Which is why, I ask, why is dark matter called "dark matter". The point being to hopefully educate.

Comment: @Tim The statement that "we can only observe less than 5% of our universe" is incorrect. The correct statement is that the theories that predict "additional 95%" (which we don't see) are not supported by the observations and therefore must be dismissed.

Comment: What are you talking about? Theories not supported by evidence? We can observe the gravitational effect of dark matter. From gravitational lensing to cosmic microwave background to a whole bunch of other observational effects. We don't have any explanation why the universe is expanding with an ever increasing acceleration. The gravity of observable matter (including black holes) is around 15% of the actual gravity we observe in the universe. Read any book written by mainstream physicists of this century and you will find that I am not wrong according to current theories.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hopefully, now you know we it's called dark matter. But call that thing "Frankenstein Particle" or "Unicorn's horn" and no scientist will argue with you if you can bring them one step closer to understanding it, they might even give a noble prize.

Comment: @Tim "Dark," all by itself is a label.  Astronomers have been applying it since the 19th century to anything in the sky that they can infer, but not actually see.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Early_history

Answer (score 2):

It's dark because it doesn't emit light. I don't know what you mean by we don't see an effect of DM on other galaxies. There is definitely [observational evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Observational_evidence) for dark matter within galaxy clusters. For instance, one sees the same sort of rotation phenomena as you see within the galactic arms (the example you sighted). The luminous mass vs. gravitational mass ratio one finds that way is in agreement with what one measures from gravitational lensing.

There are plenty of examples that are totally consistent with DM at larger than galactic scales.

Answer (score 0):

Dark matter is stuff we still do not understand yet. That is the reasoning for the term "dark". Of course dark matter is seen affecting other galaxies during galactic collisions. Dark matter is "matter" in the sense it has a gravitational effect. By field, if you mean a quantum field then it sort of makes sense. This is because according to quantum field theory all particles have their respective fields. However that does not mean it will have field like behavior. It will not really change the properties of those dark matter particles and it does not really change anything. It will still have its particle like behavior.

Comment: When I say seen I mean "seen" in the sense we have seen dark matter's gravitational effect on regular matter. We can not see dark matter. Dark matter does not interact with electromagnetic waves.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is dark matter called dark matter?

Really this is a historical misnomer. Kapteyn and others found already in the 1920s that the dynamics of stars in the Milky Way can't be explained based on the gravity that we expect due to the observed matter. They thus inferred that there would need to be additional, unseen matter. If you're behind an eyepiece on a telescope, it is rather natural to call such matter "dark", in the sense of "not visible". Dark matter also does not emit e.g. thermal radiation.

Unfortunately, "dark" would imply "black" and that is an incorrect label. Evidence for dark matter has since accumulated across astrophysics and cosmology. In particular observations of the Cosmic Microwave Background radiation tell us that this dark matter does not interact with light. Therefore, a more proper name would be "transparent matter".

So why is dark matter *still* called dark matter? Historical reasons. Or, perhaps simply because this label captivates the imagination... ;)

> Specifically, when two galaxies are near each other, the "matter" that is maintaining constant angular velocity in one galaxy should also be having an effect on the neighbouring galaxy, yet we see no such effect.

But we do. Observations of tidal streams are in the process of becoming a workhorse to learn about the properties of dark matter.

> ... the field that causes constant angular velocity for stars in one galaxy should also be having an effect on the neighbouring galaxy, yet again, we see no such effect.

But we do. For example, orbits of dwarf galaxies around the Milky Way are in agreement with the inferred total mass of the Milky Way, i.e. including dark matter.

> Is it sensible to consider the term "dark matter" to actually mean matter...

Yes, very.

> ...or is it sensible to consider "dark matter" to be some as yet unidentified effect?

I'm not sure I understand the subtle distinction that is made here, but happy to consider it if you could clarify a bit what you mean.